# SQL Server 2008 : Avg. timing in milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query

```
select 
    substring((convert(varchar, PostTime, 120)), 1, 11),
    AccountNumber,
    sum(Cast(datediff(ss, TranTime, AuthProcessedTime) as money)) / COUNT(1) AverageTime,
    COUNT(1) NumberOfCount 
from 
    AuthTransactions WITH (NOLOCK) 
group by 
    substring((convert(varchar, PostTime, 120)), 1, 11), AccountNumber
```

In this query `AverageTime` comes in sec. but I want to see it in the following format `HH:MM:SS.msmsms` because most of the time results come in milliseconds. So is it possible to see the result in this format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189794.aspx for datepart milliseconds

Comment: @Rikky do you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   Convert(date, PostTime) PostDay
   AccountNumber,
   Avg(Datediff(ms, TranTime, AuthProcessedTime) * 1.0) AverageTime,
   Count(*) NumberPerDay
FROM
   dbo.AuthTransactions 
GROUP BY
   Convert(date, PostTime),
   AccountNumber
```

There were several problems with the query that I eliminated or corrected:

- *Always* specify a length for the `char` data types.
- Don't convert dates to strings to remove the time portion. Use `DateDiff` and `DateAdd`, or since you're using SQL 2008 you can convert to `date`.
- Don't use WITH (NOLOCK) unless you really know what you're doing. It will eventually bite you.
- Don't convert to money. That's just weird. It has 2 decimal places, and if you really want that, then convert to decimal([something], 2). Otherwise someone is going to see your code and go "what the heck?" and 'fix' it for you, even if that's what you wanted. You can get a sufficiently-precise decimal conversion just by multiplying by 1.0 like I showed.
- Do specify the schema of objects. It is small, but it helps performance and (if I am not remembering incorrectly) not doing so can cause unnecessary plan recompilation.

Answer (score 0):

In your `datediff(ss,TranTime,AuthProcessedTime)`
change the ss to ms.
ms is used for milli second.

like this

```
select substring((convert(varchar,PostTime,120)),1,11),
AccountNumber,
sum(Cast (datediff(ms,TranTime,AuthProcessedTime)  as money)) / COUNT(1)
AverageTime,COUNT(1) NumberOfCount from AuthTransactions
WITH(NOLOCK) group by 
substring((convert(varchar,PostTime,120)),1,11),AccountNumber
```

Comment: @ErikE what error ? the user said that the he/she wants the answer in milliseconds so I suggest him to use mm in place of ss. Please tell me the error so I can clear myself.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua See the problems I mentioned in my query.